# Path environment for sevlet, with Tomcat 7.0

Tags: tomcat, servlets

On the command line when I am using the following command to compile, it works:

```
C:\java_works>javac HelloServlet.java -classpath 
    "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar"
```

But when I set the system environment path variable it does not work, if I use the following steps:

In system variables, create a new variable name: `SERVLET_HOME`

With the value: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib`

Then edited the system variable `path` to include: `%SERVLET_HOME%\servlet-api.jar;`

Then on the command line I use:

```
C:\java_works>javac HelloServlet.java
```

But it's not working, showing errors:

```
package javax.servlet does not exist
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK javac, the java compiler, does not look for jars on the PATH (which is used for executables) but on its classpath. But honestly, it's a long time since I used javac on the commandline and I'd like to recommend to use it implicitly through (e.g.) Ant, Maven or any IDE (Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ).